# Return column heading as a value based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 32 variables(columns), being UserId and 31 days of a month, and 350 rows. Each value under the days of the month is a number from 0 upwards, in integer format. I want to create a new dataframe where each value greater than 0 now shows its corresponding column name.

Below is an example. I want to get from table 1 to table 2, but I've not come across anything on how this can be done. Any help would be great.

```
Table 1

UserID    01.01.2019    02.01.2019    03.01.2019    04.01.2019    05.01.2019
20        1             0             1             1             1
28        1             0             0             0             1
37        0             0             0             0             1
40        1             0             0             0             0
43        1             1             1             1             0

Table 2

UserID     Date
20         01.01.2019
20         03.01.2019
20         04.01.2019
20         05.01.2019
28         01.01.2019
28         05.01.2019
37         05.01.2019
40         01.01.2019
43         01.01.2019
43         02.01.2019
43         03.01.2019
43         04.01.2019
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
Tab1 <- structure(list(UserID = c(20L, 28L, 37L, 40L, 43L), X01.01.2019 = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), X02.01.2019 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), X03.01.2019 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), X04.01.2019 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), X05.01.2019 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))

library(tidyverse)
Tab2 <- Tab1 %>% 
gather(Date,var,-UserID) %>% 
filter(var==1) %>% 
select(-var) %>% 
mutate(Date=sub("X","",.$Date)) %>% 
arrange(UserID)

Tab2

   UserID       Date
1      20 01.01.2019
2      20 03.01.2019
3      20 04.01.2019
4      20 05.01.2019
5      28 01.01.2019
6      28 05.01.2019
7      37 05.01.2019
8      40 01.01.2019
9      43 01.01.2019
10     43 02.01.2019
11     43 03.01.2019
12     43 04.01.2019
```

Comment: This is brilliant, very helpful. Could I ask, if some of the values in table 1 were bigger than 1 (so basically any values above 0 return the column heading), how would I have to alter the gather code to facilitate that?

Comment: Just use `filter(var > 0)`in the pipe

Comment: Thank you, have been incredibly helpful. I was wondering if you might be able to help me out again? I just tried converting the Date column format from character to Date, but it just returned the entire column as NA values, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Probably a problem with the format. Look at `strptime` for formatting date strings

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use-

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(melt(dt,id.vars="UserID"))[value==1,]

    UserID    variable value
 1:     20 X01.01.2019     1
 2:     28 X01.01.2019     1
 3:     40 X01.01.2019     1
 4:     43 X01.01.2019     1
 5:     43 X02.01.2019     1
 6:     20 X03.01.2019     1
 7:     43 X03.01.2019     1
 8:     20 X04.01.2019     1
 9:     43 X04.01.2019     1
10:     20 X05.01.2019     1
11:     28 X05.01.2019     1
12:     37 X05.01.2019     1
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete here is a base R option. Using `which` we first find row and column indices and then get the respective `UserID` from the row index and column names from column indices.

```
inds <- which(df == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(userID = df$UserID[inds[, 1]], variable = names(df)[inds[, 2]])

#   userID   variable
#1      20 01.01.2019
#2      28 01.01.2019
#3      40 01.01.2019
#4      43 01.01.2019
#5      43 02.01.2019
#6      20 03.01.2019
#7      43 03.01.2019
#8      20 04.01.2019
#9      43 04.01.2019
#10     20 05.01.2019
#11     28 05.01.2019
#12     37 05.01.2019
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the tidyr package there's a function called gather that will do just this. THe documentation is [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html).

Your code would be something like:

```
table2 <- table1 %>% 
        gather("Date", "Value", -UserID) %>%
        filter(Value >0) %>%
        select(-Value)
```

Comment: @Julian_Hn I think he is using `gather` in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option that uses the `stack` function, i.e.

```
subset(cbind(df[1], stack(df[-1])), values == 1)
```

which gives,

> ```
>    UserID values         ind
> 1      20      1 X01.01.2019
> 2      28      1 X01.01.2019
> 4      40      1 X01.01.2019
> 5      43      1 X01.01.2019
> 10     43      1 X02.01.2019
> 11     20      1 X03.01.2019
> 15     43      1 X03.01.2019
> 16     20      1 X04.01.2019
> 20     43      1 X04.01.2019
> 21     20      1 X05.01.2019
> 22     28      1 X05.01.2019
> 23     37      1 X05.01.2019
> ```